# How to use datediff function to show day, hour, minute, and second

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a record:

```
Depart_dt               Arrived_dt 
10/1/2013 6:15:00 AM    10/1/2013 7:25:00 AM
```

Based on my calculation, it is 0 day, one hour, and 10 minutes between the `arrived_dt` and `Depart_dt`. How do I show the result like below:

```
Day   Hour  Minute  Second
0     1     10      0
```

Comment: do you need them as separate columns?

Comment: whats the database, what did you try so far?

Comment: I use sql sever 2008

Comment: Hopefully, the data type of these columns is `datetime` (or `datetime2`), in which case they don't *have* a "date format".

Comment: @jpw - I hadn't realised it wasn't in the original question. In which case, my question to you is - how do you know? The difference between two dates on 10th January 2013 is 0 days, but so is the difference between two dates on 1st October 2013.

Comment: @vkp, it works perfectly now. Thanks. also thanks everyone else too.

Comment: @VKP or everyone else, I have two different dates as 10/1/2013 10:15:00 AM and 10/1/2013 10/1/2013 11:14:00am. Using the script to get the hour, I got 1 hour exactly. But it should be 59 minutes instead of 1 hour. any comments?

Comment: @joe..posted a changed answer.try that

Comment: @vkp, just tried. The depart-dt is 10/1/2013 10:15:00 AM and arrival-dt is 10/11/2013 7:47:00 am. Result shows 0. Select dateiff (second, depart-dt, arrived-dt)/86400. What is 86400 tho?

Comment: `86400` is the number of seconds in a day. For accuracy, i calculate the difference in seconds and do a conversion to `day`,`hour` and `minute`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84837/discussion-between-vkp-and-joe).

Comment: @vkp, it appears working now. When take 10//11/2013 7:47:00am - 10/1/2013 10:15:00am, I got 9 days, 21 hours, 57 min. I was expecting 32 min Tho. Thanks again

Comment: `datediff` takes startdate as the second argument and enddate as the third argument. not vice-versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
datediff(second,depart_dt, arrived_dt)/86400 as Day,
datediff(second,depart_dt, arrived_dt)/3600%24 as Hour,
datediff(second,depart_dt, arrived_dt)/60%60 as Minute,
datediff(second,depart_dt, arrived_dt)%60 as Second
from yourtable
```

Converting days, hours and minutes into seconds for accuracy.

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c6c63/1

Answer (score 4):

You can use modulus division on the output of the `DATEDIFF()` function for this:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(second,Depart_dt,Arrived_Dt)/(60*60*24) AS Day
      ,DATEDIFF(second,Depart_dt,Arrived_Dt)/(60*60)%24 AS Hour
      ,DATEDIFF(second,Depart_dt,Arrived_Dt)/(60)%60 AS Minute
      ,DATEDIFF(second,Depart_dt,Arrived_Dt)%60 AS Second
FROM Table1
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/04f8a/3/0)

Comment: will `DATEDIFF(hour,Depart_dt,Arrived_Dt)%24` give total difference in hour??. I think the `Q` is `day\hour\min\sec` format

Comment: Yes the total number of hours difference, and modulus division will return the remainder, so only the hours not evenly captured in the day bucket will return.  So for minutes this returns 10 instead of 70 since the total difference in minutes is 70, but only 10 of those minutes haven't already been captured in the hour bucket.

Comment: Thanks for clarification

Comment: @Hart CO, what if the difference hours between two dates is only 59 minutes, or the difference days between two dates is only 23 hours. The script above still counts as 1 hour and 1 day. Any comment?

Comment: @joe Yep, normally I do everything in seconds but wasn't thinking clearly this morning, updated accordingly.

Comment: @Hart CO, got it. Thanks again eveyone!